# Can't set width of AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, width

I'm trying to set width of AlertDialog with the following code :

```
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_main, null);
    view.findViewById(R.id.friends_bar).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MessagesPanel.this).setTitle(
                            "Messages").setAdapter(messagesAdapter,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    Log.d("Button Clicked",
                                            msgs_array.get(which)
                                                    .getTitle());
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

                    WindowManager.LayoutParams dialogLocation = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
                    dialogLocation.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
                    dialogLocation.x = (int) view.findViewById(R.id.friends_bar).getX();
                    dialogLocation.y = (int) view.findViewById(R.id.friends_bar).getY() + 40;
                    dialogLocation.width = 100;


                    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(50, 250);
                    dialog.show();
                };
            });
```

but it didn't work.. Note: x and y works fine.

I also tried :
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(dialogLocation);

Thanks :)

Comment: if not any error then debug your app.

Comment: When I tried to Log width I got -2.. any idea ?